# Does Wii MotionPlus enhance the accuracy of games created prior to its existence?

Tags: controllers, nintendo-wii

Regarding the Wii Remote + MotionPlus / Wii Remote Plus, I know the added gyroscope allows better accuracy with games which specify compatibility.

Does using the MotionPlus on a regular controller enhance the accuracy received by other games?

For example, should I be using it when I play Boom Blox or Boom Blox Block Party?

If it only enhances some earlier games, is there a master list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I understand it, MotionPlus only works with games that are expecting it. It's a periphiral, just like the Nunchuk, and any game that isn't specifically looking for it will just see an extra block of data labelled "MotionPlus stuff" and ignore it. Besides, such games won't be asking you to calibrate MotionPlus anyway, and it probably won't work well without that.

Comment: I was kind of hoping there were some pre-existing XYZ parameters that having a MotionPlus attached would make more accurate.

Comment: Even if that is the case (I'm not 100% certain either way), it would still need calibration to work properly.